# ruby webdriver ERROR: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up

Tags: ruby, caching, webdriver

I am going to find all the li elements on a page,they all have unique id in their herf perporties, some of them are hidden and click more button on the page can get them visible. here is code:

```
def open_template id=0
      sleep 1
      #try to get all the li elements that has class named like "test..." and put them into a list
      box_list=browser.lis.find_all { |div| div.class_name =~ /^test/ }   
      sleep 2
      #go though the list
      box_list.each do |each|
         str=each.a.attribute_value("href")
         #the tid number of the element should match to id
         if /\?tid=\d+/.match(str)[0].gsub!("?tid=", "").to_i==id
            # if the element is hidden, should click the "more" button and get into another page
            if each.attribute_value("style")=="display: none;"
              each.parent.parent.div(class: "title_me_h").a(class: "more").click
              sleep 2
              # begin the same thing on the new page
              open_template(id)
            end
            begin
              #if the element matchs and isn't hidden, do a click          
              each.a(class: "li_box_cj").wait_until_present 
              each.a(class: "li_box_cj").click
            rescue Exception => e
              puts "ERROR: #{e.message}"            
            end
            break
         end
      end
    end
```

when i tried to find a hidden li element, after execute the code I got element not found in the cache error, but the last action "click" was executed. I don't understand why, can anyone give me some tips? i have read all the related questions on stackoverflow but didn't get answer. Thank you advance.

Comment: After clicking, the DOM changes (make li visible), but the list you are trying loop are generated before clicking, hence exception is throw.

Comment: thank you for your kindly answer, there is a logic error in my code, need an "else" to break out of the loop, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
def open_template id=0
  sleep 1
  box_list=browser.lis.find_all { |div| div.class_name =~ /^test/ }   
  sleep 2
  box_list.each do |each|
     str=each.a.attribute_value("href")
     if /\?tid=\d+/.match(str)[0].gsub!("?tid=", "").to_i==id
        if each.attribute_value("style")=="display: none;"
          each.parent.parent.div(class: "title_me_h").a(class: "more").click
          sleep 2
          open_template(id)
        #add else here to break out of the loop
        else
        begin
          #if the element matchs and isn't hidden, do a click          
          each.a(class: "li_box_cj").wait_until_present 
          each.a(class: "li_box_cj").click
        rescue Exception => e
          puts "ERROR: #{e.message}"            
        end
        end
        break
     end
  end
end
```